# Flatten a list of dictionaries and extract data along the way

Tags: python, list, dictionary

This is the data structure that I have

```
[{
    "tree": [{
        "tree": [{
            "name": "Dinosaur Rex",
            "key": "Dinosaur Rex"
        }, {
            "name": "hats",
            "key": "hats"
        }],
        "name": "Plugin1",
        "key": "Plugin1"
    }],
    "name": "Plugins",
    "key": "plugins"
}, {
    "tree": [{
        "key": "memSwapFree",
        "name": "Swap free",
        "unit": "MB"
    }, {
        "key": "memPhysUsed",
        "name": "Physical used",
        "unit": "MB"
    }, {
        "key": "memSwapUsed",
        "name": "Swap used",
        "unit": "MB"
    }, {
        "key": "memPhysFree",
        "name": "Physical free",
        "unit": "MB"
    }],
    "name": "Memory",
    "key": "memory"
}]
```

I would like to output something like that below. I have trouble coming up with a good way of doing that.

```
[
    ['plugins', 'plugin1', 'hats'], 
    ['plugins', 'plugin1', 'Dinosaur Rex']
    ['memory', 'memPhysFree'],
    ['memory', 'memSwapFree'],
    ['memory', 'memPhysUsed'],
    ['memory', 'memSwapUsed'],
]
```

Comment: What way(s) have you come with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not too hard to do with a recursive generator, extracting the `"key"` values:

```
def flatten(lst):
    for dct in lst:
        key = dct["key"]
        if "tree" not in dct:
            yield [key] # base case
        else:
            for result in flatten(dct["tree"]): # recursive case
                yield [key] + result
```

If you want an actual list, call `list(flatten(list_of_dicts))`.

Comment: Lovely! Doing something recursive like this is what I tried but couldn't just get it right. Thanks for the help.